# Accessing MongoDB collection values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new in Meteor, and especially in MongoDB.

I have googled a lot regarding this issue but nothing found related to this.

So there is an app that contains two collections: `EventsCollection` and `RacesCollection` and runs on Meteor server.

The `RacesCollection` has number of records like:

```
RacesCollection.insert({raceId:"r1", eventId:"e1", raceName:"Moto race 1", status:"statusDetail", mode:"modeDetail"});
RacesCollection.insert({raceId:"r2", eventId:"e1", raceName:"Moto race 2", status:"statusDetail", mode:"modeDetail"});
```

This is the resultant collection which contains rows having `eventId = e1`

```
var race = RacesCollection.find({eventId: "e1"});
```

Now what i want to do is to simply access the fields of `race` into javascript, something like `race.raceId`, `race.raceName`. How to implement this? Is there any getter method for accessing particular data field?

And how to iterate through multiple rows of `race` in case it contains number of rows?

Any recommendation will be appriciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MongoDB's `find()` method returns what's called a "cursor".  In javascript, you can iterate over the cursor as in [these docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors), and access the fields of the documents using standard javascript property access.

For example (untested code, but this is the idea):

```
var raceCursor = RacesCollection.find({eventId: "e1"});
var race;
while ( raceCursor.hasNext() ) {
    race = raceCursor.next();
    console.log( race.raceName );
}
```

Since Meteor is pure javascript, it also supports using `forEach()` to iterate over the cursor's documents, as in [this example](http://docs.meteor.com/#foreach).

Comment: `forEach` can be used on arrays, but not on a MongoDB `Cursor`.  You'd have to call [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray) on the cursor if you wanted to do that.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - It seems (looking at the last example I posted in the question) that Meteor doesn't require the toArray call (even if other javascript-based drivers do).

Comment: Interesting.  So meteor must add its own layer on top of the driver to support that.

Comment: @shelman .. I've tried your code, but it shows following error on JAVASCRIPT CONSOLE in Google Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasNext'`

Comment: Yeah. mine is getting the same problem as @sohelkhalifa . funny that the documentation states that there is a hasNext method. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hasNext/

Comment: A cursor in Meteor is not the same as a cursor in MongoDB. Here's the docs for a cursor in Meteor: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection_cursor In short: use the `forEach` method, as shown in the answer by Sekai.

Comment: @PeppeL-G but using forEach you can't "stop" the iteration returning false, as would be expected when using hasNext() and next() //=

Answer (score 31):

use ForEach :

```
db.databaseName.find(
  {
    field:"valueofField"
  }
).forEach(function(obj){
    print(obj.fieldname)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem and hasNext() did not work for me.

Instead Meteor provides [fetch()](http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch) to convert a cursor to a javascript array.  So you can use:

```
var raceCursor = RacesCollection.find({eventId: "e1"});
var races = raceCursor.fetch();
for (var i=0; i<races.length; i++) {
    console.log( races[i].raceName );
}
```

Comment: It is better to use the `forEach` method instead of fetching the documents and looping through them yourself. See the answer by Sekai.

Answer (score 4):

Sekai's answer works, however, it's written from a MongoDB perspective.  From a Meteor JavaScript helper, using the variables used in the question, it would look like:

```
RacesCollection.find(
   {eventId: "e1"}
).forEach(function(race){
   console.log( race.raceName );
};
```